# HTML with Transcrypt script gives missing { before try block error

Tags: javascript, python, transcrypt

I am trying to add a javascript file that generated via Transcrypt from Python file.

However, when I add that script to my HTML file, there are some errors appeared in Console and I failed.

The Python file that I used: try.py

```
def greet():
    name = document.getElementById("Name").value
    if name == "" or name.length == 0 or name == null:
        document.getElementById("groet").innerHTML = '<p><font color="#ff0000">Hello Anonymous, may I know yor name? Please insert it below:</font></p>'
    else:
        document.getElementById("groet").innerHTML = '<p><font color="#00ff00">Hello, '+name+', thank you for introducing you</font></p>'
```

After that script, I ran the command `python3 -m transcrypt -b try.py` and a folder called "**target**" created automatically and it contains a file "try.js".

So, I wrote a HTML file which is a basic sample that shows a greeting message: hello.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<script src="__target__/try.js"></script>
</head>
<title>Insert Text</title>
<body onload=try.greet()>

<h2>Hello Demo Name</h2>

<p>
<div id = "groet">...</div>
</p>
<p>Your Name: <input name="name" type="text" maxlength="80" id="Name" value=""/> [Please enter your name]<br><br>
<button onclick=try.greet()>Refresh the greeting!</button>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I am expecting that when I clicked the button or reload the file the greeting message should be placed. However, in console I got two errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module try.js:1:13
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing { before try block hello.html:1:3
```

So, what is the problem guys?

[EDIT]
After the T.J's answer, I updated the html file as following:

```js
'use strict';import{AssertionError,AttributeError,BaseException,DeprecationWarning,Exception,IndexError,IterableError,KeyError,NotImplementedError,RuntimeWarning,StopIteration,UserWarning,ValueError,Warning,__JsIterator__,__PyIterator__,__Terminal__,__add__,__and__,__call__,__class__,__envir__,__eq__,__floordiv__,__ge__,__get__,__getcm__,__getitem__,__getslice__,__getsm__,__gt__,__i__,__iadd__,__iand__,__idiv__,__ijsmod__,__ilshift__,__imatmul__,__imod__,__imul__,__in__,__init__,__ior__,__ipow__,
__irshift__,__isub__,__ixor__,__jsUsePyNext__,__jsmod__,__k__,__kwargtrans__,__le__,__lshift__,__lt__,__matmul__,__mergefields__,__mergekwargtrans__,__mod__,__mul__,__ne__,__neg__,__nest__,__or__,__pow__,__pragma__,__proxy__,__pyUseJsNext__,__rshift__,__setitem__,__setproperty__,__setslice__,__sort__,__specialattrib__,__sub__,__super__,__t__,__terminal__,__truediv__,__withblock__,__xor__,abs,all,any,assert,bool,bytearray,bytes,callable,chr,copy,deepcopy,delattr,dict,dir,divmod,enumerate,filter,float,
getattr,hasattr,input,int,isinstance,issubclass,len,list,map,max,min,object,ord,pow,print,property,py_TypeError,py_iter,py_metatype,py_next,py_reversed,py_typeof,range,repr,round,set,setattr,sorted,str,sum,tuple,zip}from"./org.transcrypt.__runtime__.js";var __name__="__main__";export var greet=function(){var py_name=document.getElementById("Name").value;if(py_name==""||py_name.length==0||py_name==null)document.getElementById("groet").innerHTML='<p><font color="#ff0000">Hello Anonymous, may I know yor name? Please insert it below:</font></p>';
else document.getElementById("groet").innerHTML='<p><font color="#00ff00">Hello, '+py_name+", thank you for introducing you</font></p>"};

//# sourceMappingURL=hello.map
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script type="module">
      import { greet } from "./hello.js";
      document.getElementById("greetButton").onclick=greet();
    </script>
  </head>
  <title>Insert Text</title>
<body>

<h2>Hello Demo Name</h2>

<p>
<div id = "groet">...</div>
</p>
<p>Your Name: <input name="name" type="text" maxlength="80" id="Name" value=""/> [Please enter your name]<br><br>
<button id="greetButton">Refresh the greeting!</button>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @T.J. Crowder's answer, I changed the script in html as:

```
<script type="module">
  import * as hello from "./__target__/hello.js";
  window.hello = hello;
</script>
```

As explained in the tutorial of [Transcrypt](https://www.transcrypt.org/docs/html/installation_use.html#your-first-transcrypt-program).

With this way, I can call the Python function on button's click.

Comment: There is no reason for `window.hello = hello;` if you use modern event handling. And there are good reasons *not* to add to the already-crowded global namespace.

Comment: Interestingly, it failed when I not add `window.hello = hello;` line. It gives "hello is not defined".

Comment: Not if you're doing `document.getElementById("greetButton").onclick=greet();` (but with `hello`). Again, if you use an old-style attribute handler, it can't use `hello` unless you do that because (again) it can only use globals. So don't use old-style attribute handlers.

Answer (score 1):

> `import declarations may only appear at top level of a module`

is fairly clear: You're not loading the script as a module, so you can't use `import`. Add `type="module"` to the `script` tag. (But be sure that your target browsers support modules -- all modern major ones do, but you don't have to go more than a few versions back in some before module support isn't there.)

> `missing { before try block`

You have

```html
<body onload=try.greet()>
```

`try` is a keyword in JavaScript, you can't use it as an identifier. You'll need to use a different name for your `try` object. (I'll use `xtry` in the rest of this answer.)

If your code really is a module, you also won't be able to use your `xtry` as a global, even if it's declared at the top level of your code, because the top level scope of a module *isn't* global scope. You'll need to import it to use it. That also means you don't need a `script` tag for `try.js` since the `import` will do it. Remove the `onload` and your current `script` tag and instead:

```
<script type="module">
import { xtry } from "__target__/try.js";
xtry.greet();
</script>
```

That won't run until the HTML has been fully parsed and the DOM has been populated (because of the `type="module"`).

---

Side note: `onload` attribute handlers are generally not best practice, for two reasons: 1. They can only use globals, and 2. The `load` event happens **very** late in the page load cycle, waiting for all resources (including all images) to load. Sometimes that's what you want, but not often. Instead, use modern event handling (if you really need to hook up a handler on `load`) and use modern script techniques (`type="module"`, `defer`, ...).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I guess I couldn't understand a few things. First of all, the "import" error is from js file but the js file is not created by me, created by Transcrypt, automatically. Secondly, If I'm not wrong changing try.js/try.py with something like hello.js/hello.py will work. But in this case, I got an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined (hello.html:1:1).

Comment: Also, the "module" script got another error, "cannot find xtry"

Comment: @stuck - *"First of all, the "import" error is from js file but the js file is not created by me, created by Transcrypt, automatically."* Yes. And apparently it creates a JavaScript module. You have to use it as such. *"But in this case, I got an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined"* I explained in the answer why you couldn't use the identifier as a global.

Comment: *"Also, the "module" script got another error, "cannot find xtry" "* Your identifier is `hello`, not `xtry`. `xtry` in the above was just a placeholder.

Comment: Of course I know my identifier is hello, I meant I tried your xtry version in the answer and I failed :) OK, now I removed the onload part, forget about it. Also I add the script via import as module type. How can I put the script to the button's onclick?

Comment: I added the hello.js and the updated html file. I failed again.